# Tracing the Memory/Window Leaks in Android?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

How to trace the Memory Leaks in Android Development? I am working on eclipse IDE to develop the application. i cant find out how to rectify the memory or window Leaks Exceptions? Any Idea.

Mainly the Window Leaked error raises the Illegal Argument Exception? how to rectify both og this. Please Help.

Comment: A copy of the error log would help :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you really want to know how to trace memory leaks in general, this worked really well for me:

http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/2009/04/analyzing-memory-usage-off-your-android.html

... though, it almost sounds like you have a specific problem with a specific exception, and that you're not interested in tracing a memory leak.  Sounds like you have the same problem as this: [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Comment: +1 first links a good one, i didnt know all this existed and well integrated with 2.2 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I donno what caused you memory leak.
But i have suffered from memory leak due to excess of Bitmap object  to convert drawable to bitmap..

later used one single Bitmap object to rectify this problem.