# How to find Memory Leak Class/Activity in Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am New to this Android platfrom.   In one application, there is a memory leak.  But i couldn't able to find in which actiity or class the memory leak is happening.

I am using MAT to get the infirmation that the memory leak is there or not.  But not able to find which activity is leaking.

Please tell me how to find the which activity is leaking.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851483/tracing-the-memory-window-leaks-in-android

Comment: This article will show you how: http://ttlnews.blogspot.com/2010/01/attacking-memory-problems-on-android.html

Answer (score 35):

Even if this question is quiet old. I think a small tutorial with images might be helpful. So first you need to install the [MAT plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). After a restart click on **Dump HPROF file**:

[image: Device controls]

After some time (about 30 seconds) you'll get a dialog where you can click on finish. Than you get this view:

[image: Dump result]

There you left click on the biggest part and filter for **with outgoing references**. Then you get this view here:

[image]

Here you can see that I missed to delete items in my ContentManager where several items were stored in my *pending* `HashMap`.

Answer (score 5):

The best post I found yet on tracking memory leaks on android platforms is:

http://ttlnews.blogspot.com/2010/01/attacking-memory-problems-on-android.html

The first part is outdated because it's now integrated into Eclipse but most of the post is great!

Comment: The article you linked was the most helpful article I have come across for detecting memory leaks in Android. A million kudos.

Answer (score 4):

Use **LeakCanary** - a memory leak detection library for Android and Java.
LeakCanary will automatically show a notification when an activity memory leak is detected in your debug build. Installing this library is very simple.

https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Notification example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on the previous post, but it's important to realise that you absolutely should worry about memory management, especially on the resource-confined environment that is the Android mobile platform. For more on that, check here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Avoidance can only get you so far. Sometimes it's a third party library that trips up your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can see it in the DDMS.

Simply select your app package name and click update heap the above button.

Now goto Heap Tab click Cause GC.

you will find the listing of objects used.

Answer (score 0):

You can analysis android memory leaks automatically with MMAT,[MMAT github page](https://github.com/hehonghui/mmat)