# The interpretor for android ART runtime

Tags: android, c++, virtual-machine, dalvik

I am currently working with android source tree. For my work I need to go through the instruction at run time. Previously when I used Dalvik VM I hooked into by enabling the interpreter mode and going through the following file `dalvik/vm/mterp/out/InterpC-Portable.cpp`. There is a loop that continuously cycle through the instructions. I want to find something similar to this for the ART runtime.

What files should I modify?

Do I need to change something like enabling interpreter mode as I did before?

And finally how can build to libart.so? previously I typed `make libdvm`, but now if I use `make libart` I get the reply no such target libart.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: @fadden can you please help me out?

Comment: ART doesn't have an interpreter. That fact is one of its core features.

Comment: That was a workaround to get the instructions. do you have any idea how can I get the instructions?

Comment: @danfuzz there is still an interpreter. I believe it's used in for debugging, etc.

Comment: @JesusFreke Oh; I stand corrected. That's kinda surprising.

Comment: @Pbasak: I left the Dalvik team before work on Art started.  I have zero familiarity with the code, so I'm afraid I can't be any help here.

Comment: Look there for the instrumentation of the ART interpreter : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478647/android-app-java-jni-call-hooking-strategies/33695744#33695744