# Why addr2line is not able to resolve certain address to function names?

Tags: android, debugging, android-debug, adb, addr2line

I have backtraces obtained from executing the command `dumpheap -n <PID> <file>`. I have to convert these address to function names and line numbers to make these backtraces meaningful. I used addr2line to convert these addresses to function names. This is the command i used `addr2line -C -f -e <libname>.so <address>`. There are certain places where addr2line gives me $t in the place of function names but gives the filename:linenumber correctly. How should i resolve this '$t' into function name.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution myself. I replaced `addr2line` with the one provided by android `arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line` and it worked like charm.