# On Android 4.x devices (unrooted), can checkJNI be disabled from within an app?

Tags: android, android-ndk, adb, dalvik

I have a complex Andriod app, (Java and native code) originally built for Android 2.x series devices.  I've got it all working on Android 4.3 version of the emulator, but I had to use the `adb shell stop / adb shell setprop dalvik.vm.checkjni false / adb shell start` trick to turn off the checkJNI error checking. Code is using non-global pointers, but it runs well, no obvious bugs or problems.

I have configured my Linux box so a little "Digital2" low-cost Android tablet can be seen correctly by adb, and I can now load the .apk file onto the device. But the device is running Android 4.1.1, kernel version 3.0.8, and appears to have `checkjni` set to true.

I have tried several methods to disable `checkjni` on the device, but none work, and the device is not rooted.  I can use `adb shell` and `adb push`, but not to the `/data` directory.  Attempts to `su` or run `adb root` fail, so pushing a `local.prop` file does not work.

I have built the code with latest (Dec 27. 2013) development environment (Android 4.3, android-ndk-r9c), and the app runs lovely on the emulator, with checkJNI set to 0.  Is there any way I can tell a 4.x Android device - inside the app code, and using the NDK-r9c - not to use checkJNI on the `dalvik VM`?  (Note: I have tried `adb shell setprop debug.checkjni 0`, and it has no effect.)  I can install and uninstall the app successfully, but `adb logcat` on the device shows it kacking with the "stale reference" error.

I also have `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkverion` in the AndroidManifest.xml set to "=8", but the `project.properties` file in the app build directory has the entry `target=android-19`, as this is made automatically by the `ant` build tool.

Do I have to rebuild everything using Android-13 (pre "Ice Cream Sandwich") to make my app work the way it was built? Any suggestions most appreciated.  I am new to Android development, and it's a blizzard of multiple Sdk's and Ndk's.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't change the CheckJNI setting once your app is running, and there is no way to set it per-app.

However... I'm not aware of any situations where CheckJNI false-positives.  If it's flagging a problem, there really is a problem, and if you don't fix it there's a chance your app will break in the future even if it seems to be working okay now.

If you need help tracking it down, post a question with the logcat output showing the failure report and the code at the point of the failure.  You should have a complete backtrace from the native abort, from which you can get the line number (see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314273/get-function-names-from-call-stack/2480465#2480465) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001153/android-how-to-analyse-the-native-heap-dump/20012337#20012337) for more info about `addr2line`).

Comment: Thx fadden. Just correction:  To run a build using previous Android version, you need to run "../android-sdk-linux/tools/android update project --path <path to your project directory> --target android-<x>" where <X> is the version of Android you want to build for.  This action creates a new project.properites file in your project directory, and then you can run build.sh or ndk-build to rebuild your project.  I rebuilt my project using Android-13, (which uses Android 3.2, I believe).  This did not solve my "checkjni" issue.  I will post a new question about fixing stale local pointers. - Rus.

Comment: Just a followup.  The app cannot disable "checkjni", but you can use the SDK "android" utility, to change your target API from the current build target to a lower target, such as android-8.  This will also allow your app to be loaded on earlier model devices.  Specify "--target=android-8" as option to "update project". The device logcat will report "Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for SDK version 8".  After app crashes with failure to find a library, dalvik reports "Late-enabling CheckJNI" in logcat. So, you can avoid checkJNI by downgrading the API version, but maybe you don't want to.