# App automatically closes without any error

Tags: android, android-ndk, irrlicht

I am developing an app using irrlicht 3d game engine, ported it on android using the latest opengles-svn.
While creating a device by calling createDevice, the app will automatically close, without any error.
Here is how I am calling createDevice.

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "BLUE LAB TEST", "Iam at test-app.cpp");
device =createDevice( video::EDT_OGLES1, dimension2d<u32>(0, 0), 16, false, false, false);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "BLUE LAB TEST", "Iam at test-app.cpp again");
```

here is my logcat

```
02-01 09:19:28.097: D/dalvikvm(26293): GC_EXPLICIT freed 143K, 47% free 2859K/5379K, external 743K/1036K, paused 57ms
02-01 09:19:31.787: D/AndroidRuntime(26608): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-01 09:19:31.787: D/AndroidRuntime(26608): CheckJNI is OFF
02-01 09:19:31.787: D/dalvikvm(26608): creating instr width table
02-01 09:19:31.937: D/AndroidRuntime(26608): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
02-01 09:19:31.967: D/dalvikvm(26386): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 49% free 2768K/5379K, external 743K/1036K, paused 23ms
02-01 09:19:31.967: W/ActivityManager(235): No content provider found for: 
02-01 09:19:32.227: W/ActivityManager(235): No content provider found for: 
02-01 09:19:32.237: D/PackageParser(235): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl-1979495200.tmp
02-01 09:19:32.497: I/PackageManager(235): Removing non-system package:com.adstuck.test
02-01 09:19:32.497: I/ActivityManager(235): Force stopping package com.adstuck.test uid=10143
02-01 09:19:32.577: D/PackageManager(235): Scanning package com.adstuck.test
02-01 09:19:32.577: I/PackageManager(235): Package com.adstuck.test codePath changed from /data/app/com.adstuck.test-2.apk to /data/app/com.adstuck.test-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
02-01 09:19:32.577: I/PackageManager(235): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/com.adstuck.test-1.apk
02-01 09:19:33.597: D/installd(121): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.adstuck.test-1.apk' ---
02-01 09:19:33.927: D/dalvikvm(26621): creating instr width table
02-01 09:19:34.187: D/dalvikvm(26621): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/graphics/BitmapFactory$Options;.inMutable
02-01 09:19:34.367: D/dalvikvm(26621): DexOpt: load 41ms, verify+opt 235ms
02-01 09:19:34.417: D/installd(121): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.adstuck.test-1.apk' (success) ---
02-01 09:19:34.417: I/ActivityManager(235): Force stopping package com.adstuck.test uid=10143
02-01 09:19:34.427: D/PackageManager(235):   Activities: com.adstuck.test.MainActivity
02-01 09:19:34.427: W/PackageManager(235): Code path for pkg : com.adstuck.test changing from /data/app/com.adstuck.test-2.apk to /data/app/com.adstuck.test-1.apk
02-01 09:19:34.427: W/PackageManager(235): Resource path for pkg : com.adstuck.test changing from /data/app/com.adstuck.test-2.apk to /data/app/com.adstuck.test-1.apk
02-01 09:19:34.507: I/installd(121): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.adstuck.test-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.adstuck.test-1.apk@classes.dex
02-01 09:19:34.507: D/PackageManager(235): New package installed in /data/app/com.adstuck.test-1.apk
02-01 09:19:34.607: I/ActivityManager(235): Force stopping package com.adstuck.test uid=10143
02-01 09:19:34.707: D/dalvikvm(235): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1820K, 51% free 7205K/14663K, external 1343K/1855K, paused 93ms
02-01 09:19:34.807: D/dalvikvm(26324): GC_EXPLICIT freed 282K, 48% free 3037K/5831K, external 743K/1036K, paused 100ms
02-01 09:19:34.867: D/VoiceDialerReceiver(26199): onReceive Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.adstuck.test flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.voicedialer/.VoiceDialerReceiver (has extras) }
02-01 09:19:34.867: V/RecognizerEngine(26199): deleteCachedGrammarFiles /data/data/com.android.voicedialer/files/openentries.txt
02-01 09:19:34.887: D/dalvikvm(9841): GC_EXPLICIT freed 351K, 51% free 3636K/7367K, external 2637K/3270K, paused 169ms
02-01 09:19:34.887: D/PackageBroadcastService(19128): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.adstuck.test
02-01 09:19:35.087: D/dalvikvm(235): GC_EXPLICIT freed 211K, 52% free 7156K/14663K, external 1343K/1855K, paused 137ms
02-01 09:19:35.127: D/GTalkService(3162): handlePackageInstalled: re-initialize providers
02-01 09:19:35.127: D/GTalkService(3162): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] ##### searchProvidersFromIntent
02-01 09:19:35.127: D/GTalkService(3162): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] no intent receivers found
02-01 09:19:35.167: D/VoiceDialerReceiver(26199): onReceive Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.adstuck.test flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.voicedialer/.VoiceDialerReceiver (has extras) }
02-01 09:19:35.167: V/RecognizerEngine(26199): deleteCachedGrammarFiles /data/data/com.android.voicedialer/files/openentries.txt
02-01 09:19:35.197: D/PackageBroadcastService(19128): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.adstuck.test
02-01 09:19:35.207: I/installd(121): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.adstuck.test-2.apk@classes.dex
02-01 09:19:35.237: D/AndroidRuntime(26608): Shutting down VM
02-01 09:19:35.237: D/dalvikvm(26608): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 71% free 297K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 0ms+1ms
02-01 09:19:35.237: D/jdwp(26608): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-01 09:19:35.237: D/dalvikvm(26608): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-01 09:19:35.247: D/com.sonyericsson.updatecenter.launcher.UpdateCenterLauncher(26260): Got PACKAGE ADDED broadcast with package name=com.adstuck.test
02-01 09:19:35.327: D/PackageBroadcastService(19128): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED and uri=com.adstuck.test
02-01 09:19:35.477: D/AndroidRuntime(26636): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-01 09:19:35.477: D/AndroidRuntime(26636): CheckJNI is OFF
02-01 09:19:35.477: D/dalvikvm(26636): creating instr width table
02-01 09:19:35.627: D/AndroidRuntime(26636): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
02-01 09:19:35.637: I/ActivityManager(235): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.adstuck.test/.MainActivity } from pid 26636
02-01 09:19:35.687: D/AndroidRuntime(26636): Shutting down VM
02-01 09:19:35.687: D/dalvikvm(26636): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 69% free 321K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+0ms
02-01 09:19:35.687: D/jdwp(26636): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-01 09:19:35.687: D/dalvikvm(26636): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-01 09:19:35.687: I/ActivityManager(235): Start proc com.adstuck.test for activity com.adstuck.test/.MainActivity: pid=26644 uid=10143 gids={1015}
02-01 09:19:35.757: D/dalvikvm(26644): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.adstuck.test/lib/libIrrlicht.so 0x2afc8830
02-01 09:19:35.807: D/dalvikvm(26644): Added shared lib /data/data/com.adstuck.test/lib/libIrrlicht.so 0x2afc8830
02-01 09:19:35.807: D/dalvikvm(26644): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.adstuck.test/lib/libIrrlicht.so 0x2afc8830, skipping init
02-01 09:19:35.917: I/test.cpp(26644): not handled /mnt/sdcard
02-01 09:19:35.917: I/BLUE LAB TEST(26644): Iam at nativeEnvJ2c
02-01 09:19:35.987: D/libEGL(26644): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
02-01 09:19:35.987: D/libEGL(26644): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
02-01 09:19:35.997: I/ActivityManager(235): Displayed com.adstuck.test/.MainActivity: +314ms
02-01 09:19:36.007: D/libEGL(26644): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-01 09:19:36.037: D/libEGL(26644): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
02-01 09:19:36.067: I/BLUE LAB TEST(26644): Iam at nativeInitGL
02-01 09:19:36.077: D/CustomizationProvider(24223): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
02-01 09:19:36.077: I/CustomizationProvider(24223): No configuration file: /system/etc/customization/settings/com/sonyericsson/textinput/uxp/custom_settings.xml
02-01 09:19:36.087: I/Irrlicht(26644): Irrlicht Engine version 1.9.0
02-01 09:19:36.117: D/dalvikvm(2769): GC_CONCURRENT freed 831K, 53% free 3223K/6791K, external 1904K/2265K, paused 12ms+3ms
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545): Build fingerprint: 'SEMC/ST15i_1249-7721/ST15i:2.3.4/4.0.2.A.0.62/wf_v3w:user/release-keys'
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545): pid: 26644, tid: 26652  >>> com.adstuck.test <<<
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000000c
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  r0 00000001  r1 40ed2d90  r2 2f839ad0  r3 00000000
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  r4 00231550  r5 40ed1c10  r6 002315e8  r7 00000000
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  r8 2f839b48  r9 2ef1df44  10 2ef1df2c  fp 6caa4d38
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  ip 6fd46470  sp 2f839a88  lr 6fd10d84  pc 40d2b0d6  cpsr 20000030
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d0  643a64696f72646e  d1  6472656767756265
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d2  0000000043570072  d3  000000000000006c
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  3f80000000000000
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d6  4576000043340000  d7  419068c841c4cccd
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d16 403238e380000000  d17 3fe999999999999a
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d18 42eccefa43de3400  d19 3fbc71c71c71c71c
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d20 4008000000000000  d21 3fd99a27ad32ddf5
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d22 3fd24998d6307188  d23 3fcc7288e957b53b
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d24 3fc74721cad6b0ed  d25 3fc39a09d078c69f
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
02-01 09:19:36.187: I/DEBUG(10545):  scr 80000012
02-01 09:19:36.217: I/DEBUG(10545):          #00  pc 0012b0d6  /data/data/com.adstuck.test/lib/libIrrlicht.so
02-01 09:19:36.217: I/DEBUG(10545):          #01  pc 0022b958  /data/data/com.adstuck.test/lib/libIrrlicht.so
02-01 09:19:36.217: I/DEBUG(10545):          #02  pc 0022b9fa  /data/data/com.adstuck.test/lib/libIrrlicht.so
02-01 09:19:36.217: I/DEBUG(10545):          #03  pc 0012a132  /data/data/com.adstuck.test/lib/libIrrlicht.so
02-01 09:19:36.217: I/DEBUG(10545):          #04  pc 00011eb4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-01 09:19:36.217: I/DEBUG(10545):          #05  pc 00043714  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-01 09:19:36.217: I/DEBUG(10545):          #06  pc 00048eea  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-01 09:19:36.217: I/DEBUG(10545):          #07  pc 000170b4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-01 09:19:36.217: I/DEBUG(10545):          #08  pc 0001c170  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-01 09:19:36.217: I/DEBUG(10545):          #09  pc 0001b068  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-01 09:19:36.217: I/DEBUG(10545):          #10  pc 00059d2c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-01 09:19:36.217: I/DEBUG(10545):          #11  pc 00059f40  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-01 09:19:36.217: I/DEBUG(10545):          #12  pc 0004e25e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-01 09:19:36.217: I/DEBUG(10545):          #13  pc 00011910  /system/lib/libc.so
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):          #14  pc 000114d0  /system/lib/libc.so
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): code around pc:
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): 40d2b0b4 32107058 70173303 605f601f 4b32609f 
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): 40d2b0c4 9a029203 6073447b 49306bd3 60333e1c 
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): 40d2b0d4 68da5869 492e600a 600a5869 601c4a2d 
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): 40d2b0e4 605a58aa ea32f7fe 339c1c23 68336018 
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): 40d2b0f4 69d92203 97001c3b ea2ef7fe 4a261c23 
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): code around lr:
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): 6fd10d64 02800016 08bd87f0 e5964000 e5967000 
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): 6fd10d74 e2144903 1a00000e e5965000 ebffee55 
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): 6fd10d84 e2055a02 e3853001 e1500003 0a000006 
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): 6fd10d94 e5865000 e1a00006 e1a01005 e3a02001 
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): 6fd10da4 ebfffea8 e1a00004 e8bd87f0 e3a00000 
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): stack:
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a48  00231550  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a4c  40d9b247  /data/data/com.adstuck.test/lib/libIrrlicht.so
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a50  00000000  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a54  00000000  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a58  00000000  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a5c  00000000  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a60  002317f0  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a64  0000001e  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a68  0000001e  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a6c  40eaac30  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a70  000000cb  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a74  00231550  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a78  40ed1c10  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a7c  00231604  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a80  df002777  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a84  e3a070ad  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): #00 2f839a88  2ef1df2c  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a8c  6fd13ef3  /system/lib/libc.so
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a90  2f839ad0  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a94  002315f4  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a98  00000010  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839a9c  00000000  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839aa0  2f839b48  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839aa4  00231550  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839aa8  2f839ad0  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839aac  00000010  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839ab0  00000000  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839ab4  40e2b95d  /data/data/com.adstuck.test/lib/libIrrlicht.so
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545): #01 2f839ab8  2f839b38  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839abc  00000006  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839ac0  00000010  
02-01 09:19:36.227: I/DEBUG(10545):     2f839ac4  40e2b9ff  /data/data/com.adstuck.test/lib/libIrrlicht.so
02-01 09:19:36.477: I/BootReceiver(235): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
02-01 09:19:36.487: I/ActivityManager(235): Process com.adstuck.test (pid 26644) has died.
02-01 09:19:36.497: D/kernel(126): [48265.533721] binder: 235:384 transaction failed 29189, size 56-0
02-01 09:19:36.497: D/kernel(126): [48265.533843] binder: 235:384 transaction failed 29189, size 56-0
02-01 09:19:36.497: I/WindowManager(235): WIN DEATH: Window{2b347928 SurfaceView paused=false}
02-01 09:19:36.497: I/WindowManager(235): WIN DEATH: Window{2b33c240 com.adstuck.test/com.adstuck.test.MainActivity paused=false}
02-01 09:19:36.507: D/Zygote(117): Process 26644 terminated by signal (11)
02-01 09:19:36.567: W/InputManagerService(235): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 26644 uid 10143
02-01 09:19:36.597: D/kernel(126): [48265.611328] binder: 2769:2769 transaction failed 29189, size 88-0
02-01 09:19:36.627: D/CustomizationProvider(24223): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
02-01 09:19:36.627: I/CustomizationProvider(24223): No configuration file: /system/etc/customization/settings/com/sonyericsson/textinput/uxp/custom_settings.xml
02-01 09:19:36.697: D/dalvikvm(235): GC_CONCURRENT freed 873K, 48% free 7687K/14663K, external 1343K/1855K, paused 3ms+5ms
02-01 09:19:37.017: D/dalvikvm(25425): GC_CONCURRENT freed 435K, 52% free 2828K/5831K, external 743K/1036K, paused 2ms+2ms
02-01 09:19:37.287: I/iddd-events(124): Event com.sonyericsson.idd.probe.android.devicemonitor::ApplicationCrash was discarded since it was not active.
02-01 09:19:41.727: D/dalvikvm(21927): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 48% free 3614K/6919K, external 743K/1036K, paused 108ms
02-01 09:19:48.137: D/dalvikvm(19128): GC_EXPLICIT freed 258K, 45% free 3486K/6279K, external 743K/1036K, paused 89ms
02-01 09:19:48.817: D/dalvikvm(25671): GC_CONCURRENT freed 456K, 50% free 2945K/5831K, external 743K/1036K, paused 7ms+8ms
02-01 09:19:50.447: D/dalvikvm(24472): GC_CONCURRENT freed 628K, 45% free 3878K/6983K, external 743K/1036K, paused 2ms+3ms
02-01 09:19:50.627: D/dalvikvm(24472): GC_CONCURRENT freed 431K, 44% free 3955K/6983K, external 743K/1036K, paused 1ms+2ms
02-01 09:19:50.677: D/Finsky(24472): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
02-01 09:19:58.147: D/dalvikvm(24472): GC_EXPLICIT freed 594K, 51% free 3469K/6983K, external 743K/1036K, paused 122ms
02-01 09:20:08.117: D/dalvikvm(26324): GC_EXPLICIT freed 279K, 48% free 3037K/5831K, external 743K/1036K, paused 97ms
02-01 09:20:18.147: D/dalvikvm(19103): GC_EXPLICIT freed 23K, 41% free 3826K/6471K, external 743K/1036K, paused 101ms
02-01 09:20:28.137: D/dalvikvm(22126): GC_EXPLICIT freed 57K, 49% free 2819K/5447K, external 743K/1036K, paused 97ms
02-01 09:20:38.117: D/dalvikvm(26368): GC_EXPLICIT freed 62K, 49% free 2775K/5379K, external 743K/1036K, paused 76ms
02-01 09:20:48.127: D/dalvikvm(26386): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 49% free 2766K/5379K, external 743K/1036K, paused 86ms
02-01 09:20:58.137: D/dalvikvm(24223): GC_EXPLICIT freed 18K, 49% free 2778K/5379K, external 743K/1036K, paused 92ms
02-01 09:21:08.107: D/dalvikvm(25401): GC_EXPLICIT freed 13K, 48% free 2800K/5379K, external 743K/1036K, paused 94ms
```

Comment: I wouldn't say without error: `couldn't find field Landroid/graphics/BitmapFactory$Options;.inMutable`

Comment: Looks like a null pointer dereference in a native library (`/data/data/com.adstuck.test/lib/libIrrlicht.so`).  Use `addr2line` to figure out where in the code that is.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314273/get-function-names-from-call-stack/2480465#2480465 or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001153/android-how-to-analyse-the-native-heap-dump/20012337#20012337 .