# setprop libc.debug.malloc = 1 is not working

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-ndk, native

I tried to use setprop libc.debug.malloc = 1 to find out leak. 
I made an demo program and introduced memory leak in that but the above flag is not able to detect this leak.
I tried below commands:
adb shell setprop libc.debug.malloc 1
adb shell stop
adb shell start

```
jstring Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv* env,
jobject thiz) {
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
p[1] = 100;
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`libc.debug.malloc` is not valgrind.  It tracks native heap allocations, but doesn't really detect leaks directly.  It works best in conjuction with DDMS; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386339/how-to-use-ddms-for-memory-leaks-in-c-code/15398651#15398651) for information about using it for native leak chasing (and maybe [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768463/detecting-native-memory-leaks-in-android-jni-code/3773507#3773507)).

(Note you *can* use valgrind on recent versions of Android, but getting it set up can be an adventure.)

FWIW, different levels of `libc.debug.malloc` are reasonably good at finding use-after-free and buffer overruns:

```
/* 1  - For memory leak detections.
 * 5  - For filling allocated / freed memory with patterns defined by
 *      CHK_SENTINEL_VALUE, and CHK_FILL_FREE macros.
 * 10 - For adding pre-, and post- allocation stubs in order to detect
 *      buffer overruns.
```

For example, if you set `libc.debug.malloc = 10` and add a `free()` call to your example above, you'll likely get a warning message from the library because you set `p[1]` rather than `p[0]`.

Comment: Thanks.I tired to free also and it gives me logs but didn't mention anything about lib libhello-jni.so (it's my project so file),although logs have pid and component package name but,this information is very less ( function name  where is occurred would be more helpful). I also tried valgrind, it provide memory leaks and both invalid write, but it makes app very slow. The app which I need to test is crashes randomly after some-time.I am looking for way which provides memory leak and memory corruption while app remain quite responsive.

Comment: Setting libc.debug.malloc to 5 or 10 will find a fair number of problems.  It's not as thorough as valgrind -- it won't help you with stack trashers or uninitialized values, for example -- but it's much faster.